# Connect 4 Alpha-beta pruning possibly fails :(

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have been working for a while with artificial intelligence problems and in this week i have tried to code AI to connect 4 with python. First I had problems with copying board but I figured out that in python you need to use deepcopy to avoid copying errors.

Finally I managed to create alpha-beta pruning algorithm and it works OK but then I tested my algo in depth 8 against online alpha-beta pruning algo in depth 6 and surprisingly my algorithm lost. I created evaluation function with harvard's instructors and modified alpha-beta from msavenski's code (links are in the code)

Could some who have been working with these problem longer check that my algo and evaluation function works as expected because im quite sure that there is some mistake. I know that I could use tranposition tables, deep iteration and so on to make code faster and more effective but my other goal is to keep it simply.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import copy

class ConnectFour:
    def __init__(self):
        self.moves = 0  #The count of moves, 42 moves is equal than board is full
        self.turn = 0  #Use this variable to recognize which one player turn is it

    def PrintGameBoard(self, board):
        print('  0   1   2   3   4   5   6') # This function just raws a board
        for i in range(5, -1, -1):
            print('|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|')
            print("| ",end="")
            for j in range(7):
                print(board[i][j],end="")
                if j != 6:
                    print(" | ",end="")
                else:
                    print(" |")
        print('`---------------------------´')

    def LegalRow(self, col, board):
        stacks = [[x[i] for x in board] for i in range(len(board[0]))] # This function checks stack of given column and return the row where you can draw mark. If the stack is full return -1
        countofitems = stacks[col].count("x") + stacks[col].count("o") # count of items in stack
        if (countofitems) < 6:
            return (countofitems)
        else:
            return -1

    def LegalMoves(self, board):
        legalmoves = []
        stacks = [[x[i] for x in board] for i in range(len(board[0]))] 
        order = [3,2,4,1,5,0,6]
        for i in order:
            if self.LegalRow(i, board)!=-1:
                legalmoves.append(i)
        return legalmoves

    def MakeMove(self, board, col, player, row):
        board[row][col] = player # This function make a move and increases count of moves
        self.moves += 1
        return board

    def UnmakeMove(self, board, col, row):
        board[row][col] = " " # This function make a move and increases count of moves
        self.moves -= 1
        return board

    def IsWinning(self, currentplayer, board):
        for i in range(6): # This function returns True or False depending on if current player have four "tila" in a row (win)
            for j in range(4):
                if board[i][j] == currentplayer and board[i][j+1] == currentplayer and board[i][j+2] == currentplayer and board[i][j+3] == currentplayer:
                    return True
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(7):
                if board[i][j] == currentplayer and board[i+1][j] == currentplayer and board[i+2][j] == currentplayer and board[i+3][j] == currentplayer:
                    return True     
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(4):
                if board[i][j] == currentplayer and board[i+1][j+1] == currentplayer and board[i+2][j+2] == currentplayer and board[i+3][j+3] == currentplayer:
                    return True
        for i in range(3,6):
            for j in range(4):
                if board[i][j] == currentplayer and board[i-1][j+1] == currentplayer and board[i-2][j+2] == currentplayer and board[i-3][j+3] == currentplayer:
                    return True
        return False

    def PlayerMove(self, board, player):
        allowedmove = False     # This function ask players move when its his turn and returns board after making move.
        while not allowedmove:
            try:
                print("Choose a column where you want to make your move (0-6): ",end="")
                col =input()
                col=int(col)
                row = self.LegalRow(col, board)
            except (NameError, ValueError, IndexError, TypeError, SyntaxError) as e:
                print("Give a number as an integer between 0-6!")
            else:
                if row != -1 and (col<=6 and col>=0):
                    board[row][int(col)] = player
                    self.moves += 1
                    allowedmove = True
                elif col>6 or col<0:
                    print("The range was 0-6!!!")
                else:
                    print("This column is full")
        return board

    def SwitchPlayer(self, player): # This function gives opponent player's mark
        if player=="x":
            nextplayer="o"
        else:
            nextplayer="x"
        return nextplayer

    def evaluation(self, board): # This function evaluate gameboard (heuristic). The rules of evaluation are in site: http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic788088.files/Assignment%203/asst3c.pdf
        list = []
        player = "x"
        opponent = "o"
        if self.IsWinning(player, board):
            score = -512
        elif self.IsWinning(opponent, board):
            score = +512
        elif self.moves==42:
            score=0
        else:
            score = 0
            for i in range(6):  #append to list horizontal segments
                for j in range(4):
                    list.append([str(board[i][j]),str(board[i][j+1]),str(board[i][j+2]),str(board[i][j+3])])
            for i in range(3): #append to list vertical segments
                for j in range(7):
                    list.append([str(board[i][j]),str(board[i+1][j]),str(board[i+2][j]),str(board[i+3][j])])
            for i in range(3): #append to list diagonal segments
                for j in range(4):
                    list.append([str(board[i][j]),str(board[i+1][j+2]),str(board[i+2][j+2]),str(board[i+3][j+3])])
            for i in range(3, 6): #append to list diagonal segments
                for j in range(4):
                    list.append([str(board[i][j]),str(board[i-1][j+2]),str(board[i-2][j+2]),str(board[i-3][j+3])])
            for k in range(len(list)): #add to score with rules of site above
                if ((list[k].count(str("x"))>0) and (list[k].count(str("o"))>0)) or list[k].count(" ")==4:
                    score += 0
                if list[k].count(player)==1 and list[k].count(opponent)==0:
                    score -= 1
                if list[k].count(player)==2 and list[k].count(opponent)==0:
                    score -= 10
                if list[k].count(player)==3 and list[k].count(opponent)==0:
                    score -= 50
                if list[k].count(opponent)==1 and list[k].count(player)==0:
                    score += 1
                if list[k].count(opponent)==2 and list[k].count(player)==0:
                    score += 10
                if list[k].count(opponent)==3 and list[k].count(player)==0:
                    score += 50
            if self.turn==player:
                score -= 16
            else:
                score += 16
        return score

    def maxfunction(self, board, depth, player, alpha, beta):
        opponent = self.SwitchPlayer(player)
        self.turn = opponent
        legalmoves = self.LegalMoves(board)
        if (depth==0) or self.moves==42:
            return self.evaluation(board)
        value=-1000000000
        for col in legalmoves:
            row = self.LegalRow(col, board)
            newboard = self.MakeMove(board, col, opponent, row)
            value = max(value, self.minfunction(board, depth-1, opponent,alpha, beta))
            newboard = self.UnmakeMove(board, col, row)
            if value >= beta:
                return value
            alpha = max(alpha, value)
        return value

    def minfunction(self, board, depth, opponent, alpha, beta):
        player = self.SwitchPlayer(opponent)
        self.turn = player
        legalmoves = self.LegalMoves(board)
        if (depth==0) or self.moves==42:
            return evaluation(board)
        value=1000000000
        for col in legalmoves:
            row = self.LegalRow(col, board)
            newboard = self.MakeMove(board, col, player, row)
            value = min(value, self.maxfunction(board, depth-1, player ,alpha, beta))
            newboard = self.UnmakeMove(board, col, row)
            if value <= alpha:
                return value
            beta = min(beta, value)
        return value

    def alphabetapruning(self, board, depth, opponent, alpha, beta): #This is the alphabeta-function modified from: https://github.com/msaveski/connect-four
        values = []
        cols = []
        value = -1000000000
        for col in self.LegalMoves(board):
            row = self.LegalRow(col, board)
            board = self.MakeMove(board, col, opponent, row)
            value = max(value, self.minfunction(board, depth-1, opponent, alpha, beta))
            values.append(value)
            cols.append(col)
            board = self.UnmakeMove(board, col, row)
        largestvalue= max(values)
        print(cols)
        print(values)
        for i in range(len(values)):
            if largestvalue==values[i]:
                position = cols[i]
                return largestvalue, position

    def searchingfunction(self, board, depth, opponent):
        #This function update turn to opponent and calls alphabeta (main algorithm) and after that update new board (add alphabeta position to old board) and returns new board.
        newboard = copy.deepcopy(board)
        value, position=self.alphabetapruning(newboard, depth, opponent, -10000000000, 10000000000)
        board = self.MakeMove(board, position, opponent, self.LegalRow(position, board))
        return board

def PlayerGoesFirst():
    print("Player is X and AI is O") #This function just ask who goes first
    player = 'x'
    opponent = 'o'
    print('Do you want to play first? (y/n) : ',end="")
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

def PlayAgain():
    print('Do you want to play again? (y/n) :',end="") #This function ask if player want to play new game
    return input().lower().startswith('y')

def main():
    print("Connect4") #The main function. This ask player mark, initialize gameboard (table), print board after each turn, ask players move, make AI's move and checks after each move is game is tie/win or lose.
    print("-"*34)
    while True:
        connectfour = ConnectFour()
        gameisgoing = True
        table  = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(6):
                table[j].append(" ")
        player = "x"
        opponent = "o"
        if PlayerGoesFirst():
            turn = "x"
        else:
            turn = "o"
        while gameisgoing:
            connectfour.PrintGameBoard(table)
            if turn=="x":
                table = connectfour.PlayerMove(table, player)
                if connectfour.IsWinning(player, table):
                    connectfour.PrintGameBoard(table)
                    print('You won the game!')
                    gameisgoing = False
                else:
                    if connectfour.moves==42:
                        connectfour.PrintGameBoard(table)
                        print('Game is tie')
                        gameisgoing=False
                    else:
                        turn = "o"
            else:
                table = connectfour.searchingfunction(table, 6, opponent) #Here is AI's move. Takes as input current table (board), depth and opponents mark. Output should be new gameboard with AI's move.
                if connectfour.IsWinning(opponent, table):
                    connectfour.PrintGameBoard(table)
                    print('Computer won the game')
                    gameisgoing = False
                else:
                    if connectfour.moves==42:
                        connectfour.PrintGameBoard(table)
                        print('Game is tie')
                        gameisgoing=False
                    else:
                        turn = "x"
        if not PlayAgain():
            print("Game ended")
            print("-"*34)
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that yes, you do need to use deepcopy

Comment: I assume that my algorithm is correct but my evaluation function is not just enough powerful. Can someone confirm this claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation looks OK and it plays reasonable moves, too.

It is difficult to make assumptions about the playing strength from one game alone. You would need to run more games to get reliable statistics. For instance, by varying the start position and let the both engines play once as 'X' and once as '0'.

There is also a certain luck factor involved. Alpha-beta in general leads to better play when the search depth is increased. In some positions, however, it may end up playing a bad move that it would not have played in a more shallow search.

Also different evaluation functions have this effect. Even if one evaluation function is worse, there are certain positions where the bad evaluation function will lead to a better move.

The luck factor only goes away if you play enough games or if your search is so deep that it can see all variations to the end. Connect 4 is a solved game. If the algorithm is perfect, the first player to move will always win. That is the only objective way to point out a bug in the search. Heuristics, like your evaluation function, will always have weak spots.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if I want to play perfect, I need to set depth to 42 and check all 4,531,985,219,092 states and make transposition table about rewards.